# How to make global class var in the class method

Tags: python, class, methods, instance, global

I want to make a `global` `instance` of `class 'test'` if condition is satisfied.

I just wrote code intuitively, which is not working. How can I fix it?

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, a=0, b=0):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def set_glob(self, check):
        if check:
            temp = test(1,1)
            global r1 = temp  ##<- syntax error at " = "
            global r2 = self  ##<- syntax error at " = "

    a=test(1,2)
    a.set_glob(True)
```

Comment: That's not how the `global` statement works. You declare that a variable is global with `global r1` at the top of the function. Then, later, you just assign to that variable with `r1 = temp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things. You need to declare globals on a separate line. Then, you need to worry about when `test` as a variable name comes into existance... its after the class definition has completed.

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, a=0, b=0):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def set_glob(self, check):
        if check:
            temp = test(1,1)
            global r1
            global r2
            r1 = temp
            r2 = self

a=test(1,2)
a.set_glob(True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
global r1
r1 = temp
global r2
r2 = self
```

IIRC, when you declare `global x`, you are stating that for the remainder of the scope that you're in, you plan to work with `x` as a global variable.

Comment: Exactly, the mistake is trying to declare the global and assign it in the same statement. Python does not allow this

Answer (score 1):

```
class test:
def __init__(self, a=0, b=0):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b

def set_glob(self, check):
    if check:
        temp = test(1,1)
        global r1 
        r1 = temp 
        global r2 
        r2 = self  

a=test(1,2)
a.set_glob(True)
```

Explanation:

First you need to specify that you are accessing the global variables `r1` and `r2` by `global r1` and `global r2` and then assign/update that variables by `r1 = temp` and `r2  = self`